# How can I capture a value from a string and then remove it?

Tags: python, regex, string

I'm trying to get the number from a string and then remove that number.  For instance, I'm going to have a string like '42Xmessage' where 42 is the number I want (it could be any number of digits) and it's terminated by an X.

How can I get the number in a variable and then get the message part (without the number and X) in another variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do

```
'42Xmessage'.split('X')
```

to return

```
['42', 'message']
```

This isn't very general, but you can get more information from the [string](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) or [re](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) module documentation.

Comment: Very clean.  Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Use [`partition`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition):

```
>>> s = '42Xmessage'
>>> s.partition('X')
('42', 'X', 'message')
>>> s.partition('X')[0]
'42'
```

Comment: This is a good answer because this method splits the string only at the first occurrence of 'X' so there wouldn't be any conflicts if the message had an 'X'

Answer (score 1):

Using regex:

```
import re
s = '42Xmessage'
pattern = re.compile("([0-9]+)X")
print pattern.findall(s)[0]
```

For this part of your question:

"How can I get the number in a variable and then get the message part (without the number and X) in another variable?"

```
import re
s = '42Xmessage'
pattern = re.compile("([0-9]+)X([a-z]+)", re.IGNORECASE)
num, msg = pattern.findall(s)[0][:2]
```

For the pattern, `[0-9]` is the number set from 0 to 9. `([0-9]+)X` finds any number followed by an `X`. Similarly, `X([a-z]+)`, any string after the X.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try re.sub?

```
import re
re.sub('\d+X(.*)','\g<1>','42Xmesssage')
```

The first argument is a regex that captures everything that follows a "sequence of digits followed by an X". You are replacing the string with what is captured by (.*) which is specified using '\g<1>'.*